# cs-cart make the home page full width withouht affect the other pages

Tags: responsive-design, customization, cs-cart

I need to make the cs-cart home page full width and I'm not able to sort out how to do that.
I can change the "maximal widht" parameter but it affect the whole website.
Any suggestions ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use hook **index:content** to add all content into a new div that can have different class for homepage and base on that you can change the css only for hompage

For doing that you can use **My Changes** add-on:

Please add files:

1.

`design/themes/[THEME_NAME]/templates/addons/my_changes/hooks/index/content.pre.tpl`

with content

```
{if $runtime.controller=='index'}<div class="homepage">{/if}
```

2.

```
design/themes/[THEME_NAME]/templates/addons/my_changes/hooks/index/content.post.tpl
```

with content

`{if $runtime.controller=='index'}</div>{/if}`

Please add custom CSS:

1. [image]
2. [image]
3. please add css and save

`.homepage .container-fluid{ max-width: 100%; }`

**The custom modification is for CS-Cart 4.2.x / 4.3.x on Responsive theme and also require My Changes add-on to be active.**

Comment: Hi, thank you for your suggestion. I'll try to do that. I already used the Mychanges for other customizations but I didn't find the right solution for the homepage. thanks !